# Git Push into an Empty Repository error: failed to push some refs to

Tags: git, repository, push, commit

I've a problem with GIT for push into an empty repository with this error when I do `git push --set-upstream origin master`.

On Windows I type in project's folder:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://almatoolbox.visualstudio.com/xxxxxxx/_git/TS_smartroad-tests
git add .
git commit

git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

git push --set-upstream origin master
```

then I type:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

but I have this error:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://almatoolbox.visualstudio.com/ANAS/_git/TS_smartroad-tests'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I want deploy my project folder into branch master and develop. Is it possible?
If i do git pull origin master i have this error:

```
git pull origin master
From https://almatoolbox.visualstudio.com/ANAS/_git/TS_smartroad-tests
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

git remote -vv
origin  https://almatoolbox.visualstudio.com/xxxxxxx/_git/TS_smartroad-tests (fetch)
origin  https://almatoolbox.visualstudio.com/xxxxxxx/_git/TS_smartroad-tests (push)
```

and my branches are:

```
git branch -vv
develop 87d2624 [origin/develop] Deleted pom.xml
* master  824e4a7 ok
```

Comment: Did you read the guidance in the git error, or any of the (very many) Qs, As, blog posts and articles about that issue?

Comment: Read the `hint` in the error message

Comment: remote is EMPTY!!! if i do git pull: I have error:
git pull origin master
From https://almatoolbox.visualstudio.com/xxxxxxxx/_git/TS_smartroad-tests
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: You remote is certainly not empty. You've created a repository and initialized it with `README` or `.gitignore`. To see the diff: `git fetch origin && git diff origin/master HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

Your remote is NOT empty. That's exactly what the error messages are telling you.

Proof:

1. run `git fetch --all`
2. then `git log --graph --oneline --all`

You will see `origin/master`, a reference to the existing master branch on the remote. It and any other remote branches will be colored red depending on how git is configured.

**⚠️ Warning**: I hesitate to give you the following information, because you show signs of not understanding git, and run the risk making an irrecoverable risk. *Proceed at your own risk.*

If you are **absolutely sure** that you don't want any of the existing commits in `origin/master`, such as if @phd is correct that it is just the default `README` created by GitHub<sup>1</sup>, you can:

1. `git checkout master` (to make sure you are on master locally)
2. `git push --force`: this will overwrite `master` on your remote.

---

<sup>1</sup>When you create a fresh GitHub repo, can tell it not to create an initial commit with a default `README.md`